# In the following code, are the NSUserDefaults settings reset each time we open the app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm slowly getting a better grasp of objects scope and how they can be passed around in an app.   The Breadcrumbs sample project uses NSUserDefaults to store settings.  From looking at the code in the app delegate and from online documentation I noticed that the defaultsDictionary variable is instantiated each time the method willFinishLaunchingWithOptions runs. Therefore I'm assuming that every time we open the sample project, and if we changed the settings previously, our settings will be overridden by the willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Am I correct in this assumption and can confidently say that the settings will always be reset to the default values provided in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Here is the sample code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit // for MKUserTrackingModeNone

@objc(BreadcrumbAppDelegate)
@UIApplicationMain
class BreadcrumbAppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

    // The app delegate must implement the window @property
    // from UIApplicationDelegate @protocol to use a main storyboard file.
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // it is important to registerDefaults as soon as possible,
        // because it can change so much of how your app behaves
        //
        var defaultsDictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]

        // by default we track the user location while in the background
        defaultsDictionary[TrackLocationInBackgroundPrefsKey] = true as NSNumber

        // by default we use the best accuracy setting (kCLLocationAccuracyBest)
        defaultsDictionary[LocationTrackingAccuracyPrefsKey] = kCLLocationAccuracyBest as NSNumber

        // by default we play a sound in the background to signify a location change
        defaultsDictionary[PlaySoundOnLocationUpdatePrefsKey] = true as NSNumber

        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultsDictionary)

        //print(defaultsDictionary)
        //dump(defaultsDictionary)

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        //..
        return true
    }

}
```

I would like to say my assumption is wrong but I'm not making the mental connection of how the willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is skipped the next time the user opens the app therefore not resetting the settings.  Based on what I've read, I assume the willFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is fired automatically by the run time environment each time.  Any info is greatly appreciated as I'm still learning.

Comment: I've given you some sample code and **another reason this won't do what you're hoping it'll do**, let me know if my answer helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. `UserDefaults register(defaults:)` is simply a way to get a value from `UserDefaults` if there isn't an explicit value saved for a given key.

Initially, `UserDefaults` is empty. If you try to get a value for a key, you will get back `nil`. If you explicitly store a value for a key, then getting a value for that key will of course give you that stored value.

Using `register(defaults:)` only changes one part of that behavior. If you try to read a value for a key and there currently isn't a value, then `UserDefaults` will return whatever registered default there is for the key, if any, and return that. If there is no registered default for the key, then you get `nil`.

`register(defaults:)` does not reset any values. It does not replace any values. It's only there as an in-memory fallback when reading non-existent values.

Comment: Most important, `register` doesn't _write into_ the on-disk UserDefaults property list.